# Does the metal receptacle box for 6-30 NEMA need to be grounded?

Tags: electrical, grounding, subpanel, 120-240v

I have a 240 VAC portable heater with a 6-30 NEMA-style plug.  I am finishing the 3rd floor of our house.  I installed a sub panel fed with a 50A service using 6 AWG THHN.  Installed a 30-amp 2-pole breaker in sub panel.  10/2 black and white to breaker poles, bare ground to ground bar inside sub panel.

Does the metal receptacle box need grounded?

Answer (score 3):

### Yes, ground the box

Ground the box as you would for any other metal box -- with a ground pigtail that matches the gauge of the ground wires inside.

Comment: Or, if the receptacle is installed hard-flush with metal-metal contact to box cover and cover to box (not relying on screw threads for continuity), you can put the ground wire only on the box, and allow the forementioned to ground the socket.

Answer (score 1):

The pertinent National Electrical Code Article to support ThreePhaseEel's post, attention to (C):

> **250.148 Continuity and Attachment of Equipment Grounding Conductors to Boxes.** If circuit conductors are spliced within a box or terminated on equipment within or supported by a box, all equipment grounding conductor(s) associated with any of those circuit conductors shall be connected within the box or to the box with devices suitable for the use in accordance with 250.8 and 250.148(A) through (E).
>
> *Exception: The equipment grounding conductor permitted in 250.146(D) shall not be required to be connected to the other equipment grounding conductors or to the box.*
>
> **(A) Connections.** Connections and splices shall be made in accordance with 110.14(B) except that insulation shall not be required.
>
> **(B) Grounding Continuity.** The arrangement of grounding connections shall be such that the disconnection or the removal of a receptacle, luminaire, or other device fed from the box does not interfere with or interrupt the grounding continuity.
>
> **(C) Metal Boxes.** A connection shall be made between the one or more equipment grounding conductors and a metal box by means of a grounding screw that shall be used for no other purpose, equipment listed for grounding, or a listed grounding device.
>
> **(D) Nonmetallic Boxes.** One or more equipment grounding conductors brought into a nonmetallic outlet box shall be arranged such that a connection can be made to any  tting or device in that box requiring grounding.

The pertinent Article to support Harper's comment, attention to (A) if you have a surface mount box or (B) if you have a specification grade self-grounding receptacle and a flush box:

> **250.146 Connecting Receptacle Grounding Terminal to Box.**
>   An equipment bonding jumper shall be used to connect the grounding terminal of a grounding-type receptacle to a grounded box unless grounded as in 250.146(A) through (D). The equipment bonding jumper shall be sized in accordance with Table 250.122 based on the rating of the overcurrent device protecting the circuit conductors.
>
> **(A) Surface-Mounted Box.** Where the box is mounted on the surface, direct metal-to-metal contact between the device yoke and the box or a contact yoke or device that complies with 250.146(B) shall be permitted to ground the receptacle to the box. At least one of the insulating washers shall be removed from receptacles that do not have a contact yoke or device that complies with 250.146(B) to ensure direct metal-to-metal contact. This provision shall not apply to cover-mounted receptacles unless the box and cover combination are listed as providing satisfactory ground continuity between the box and the receptacle. A listed exposed work cover shall be permitted to be the grounding and bonding means when (1) the device is attached to the cover with at least two fasteners that are permanent (such as a rivet) or have a thread locking or screw or nut locking means and (2) when the cover mounting holes are located on a  at non-raised portion of the cover.
>
> **(B) Contact Devices or Yokes.** Contact devices or yokes designed and listed as self-grounding shall be permitted in conjunction with the supporting screws to establish equipment bonding between the device yoke and  flush-type boxes.